# How to access elements from finite scroll with Capybara / Poltergeist and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

For a pedagogical project I am trying to count the number of lesson elements on the following page: https://www.edx.org/course/subject/computer-science

I am using Poltergeist as a web driver to access the page, but since the page is using a javascript function to add more entries after page load when the user is scrolling down, I then need to replicate that with Poltergeist.

I have tried to scroll down using:

evaluate_script("page.scrollPosition = { top: page.scrollPosition + 1000, left: 0 };")

or

execute_script("page.scrollPosition = { top: page.scrollPosition + 1000, left: 0 };")

It does not seem to work.

Is there any way for Poltergeist to get to the bottom of the page so that the javascript loads all the elements in the (in)finite loop?
Once they are loaded, they are easy to count.

Comment: http://www.osmonov.com/2013/02/how-to-scroll-with-capybara-and.html

Comment: Tried that before, but doesn't seem to scroll to make the new elements appear. I take a screenshot in Poltergeist and it doesn't show new elements after this code executes., even including "sleep 5" afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

execute_script is called to execute javascript in the "browser" -- I'm not sure what the 'page' object you're trying to set values on is, but you probably want something more like

```
execute_script('window.scroll(0,1000);')
```

As a more complete example

```
@session.visit 'https://www.edx.org/course/subject/computer-science'
count = @session.all(:css, '.discovery-card', minimum: 1).length()
puts "there are #{count} discovery cards"
@session.execute_script('window.scroll(0,1000);')
new_count = @session.all(:css, '.discovery-card', minimum: count+1, wait: 30).length()
puts "there are now #{new_count} discovery cards"
```

Comment: Tried the following code:   `browser=Capybara.current_session
  browser.visit "https://www.edx.org/course/subject/computer-science"
  browser.execute_script('window.scroll(0,2500);')
  sleep 5
  browser.save_screenshot('app/file1.png', full: true)` no luck with getting new elements

Comment: Firstly you should be checking for contents to be on the page before calling execute_script - since it's possible for visit to be fully asynchronous - secondly you shouldn't be using sleep -- just check for new elements to be on the page - I've added a more complete example - the first call to #all will wait for the initial elements due to the minimum: 1 option, and then the call to #all after scrolling waits for new elements due to the minimum: count+1 option